# How can I save firebase push notification device local when app closed in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, hive

**I use Hive_flutter and flutter_local_notifications: ^13.0.0. And I don't have any about saving notifications device local idea when app closed.  Can you help me? thanks for your insteresting.**

```
int badgesCount = 0;
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

class PushNotificationsService {
  Future initialise() async {
    iOSPermission();
    messaging.getToken().then((token) async {
      print('token is $token');
    });

    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/ic_stat_name');
    DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS =
        DarwinInitializationSettings(
            onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveIos);

    InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
      iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
    );

    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (payload) async {
        if (payload != "") {
          log(payload.toString());
        }
      },
    );

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(
      (RemoteMessage message) async {
        if (message.notification != null) {
          badgeCount += 1;

          final remoteModel = RemoteMessageModel.fromJson(message.toMap());
          await StorageHiveHelper().save(remoteModel);

          var data = message.notification;
          var title = data?.title.toString();
          var body = data?.body.toString();
          var image = message.data['image'] ?? '';
          var type = message.data['type'] ?? '';
          var id = '';
          id = message.data['type_id'] ?? '';
          if (Platform.isIOS) return;
          if (image != null && image != 'null' && image != '') {
            return await generateImageNotication(
                title ?? "", body ?? "", image, type, id);
          }
        }
      },
    );

    messaging.getInitialMessage().then((RemoteMessage? message) {
      if (message != null) {
        log("Initial Message: " + (message.data.toString()));
        pushToNavigate(message);
      }
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp
        .listen((RemoteMessage message) => pushToNavigate(message));

    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(getBackGroundMessage);
  }

  pushToNavigate(RemoteMessage? message) async {
    var type = await message?.data['type'] ?? '';
    log("OnDidReceiveIOS: " + (message?.data.toString() ?? "null ios payload"));
    log(type);

    if (type == 'products') {
      navService.pushNamed("product/detail", args: 631509);
    }
  }

  void iOSPermission() async {
    await messaging.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );
  }

  void onDidReceiveIos(
      int id, String? title, String? body, String? payload) async {
    log("OnDidReceiveIOS: " + (payload?.toLowerCase() ?? "null ios payload"));
    try {
      var iosDetail = const DarwinNotificationDetails(
          presentBadge: true,
          presentAlert: false,
          presentSound: true,
          sound: "cash.caf");

      var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(iOS: iosDetail);

      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          id, title, title, platformChannelSpecifics,
          payload: jsonEncode(payload ?? {}));
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

***I tried saving the message to hive here. It working when app is on but it was not working when the app was totally closed***

```
  Future<void> getBackGroundMessage(RemoteMessage message) async {
    badgeCount += 1;
    await FlutterAppBadger.updateBadgeCount(badgeCount);
   final remoteModel = RemoteMessageModel.fromJson(message.toMap());

    await StorageHiveHelper().save(remoteModel);
  }
}

const String _sound = "notification_sound";

void display(
  RemoteMessage message,
  NotificationDetails notificationDetails,
) async {
  try {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      message.hashCode,
      message.notification?.title,
      message.notification?.body,
      notificationDetails,
      payload: jsonEncode(message.data),
    );
  } on Exception catch (e) {
    debugPrint(e.toString());
  }
}

Future<void> generateSimpleNotication(
    String title, String msg, String type, String id, RemoteMessage pay) async {
  try {
    if (Platform.isIOS) return;
    log("Payload" + (pay.toMap().toString()));
    final id = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000;

    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = const AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'high_importance_channels',
      'High Importance Notifications',
      playSound: true,

      sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound(_sound),
      largeIcon: DrawableResourceAndroidBitmap('@drawable/ic_stat_name'),
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.max,  );
    var iosDetail = const DarwinNotificationDetails(
        presentAlert: true, presentSound: true, sound: "cash.caf");

    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
        android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOS: iosDetail);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        id, title, msg, platformChannelSpecifics,
        payload: jsonEncode(pay.data));
  } on Exception catch (e) {
    debugPrint(e.toString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the main problem. You just want to display the notifications when app is closed or in background? Or you really need to save them to the local database? Anyways, try using this class

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

class PushNotificationService {
  static FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  static final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notificationPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  static const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'high_importance_channel', // id
    'High Importance Notifications', // title
    description:
        'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
    importance: Importance.high,
  );
  static String? idPush;
  static StreamController<RemoteMessage> _messageStream =
      StreamController.broadcast();
  static Stream<RemoteMessage> get messagesStream => _messageStream.stream;

  static Future _backgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
    _messageStream.add(message);
    // implement your actions here
  }

  static Future _onMessageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
    _messageStream.add(message);
    // implement your actions here, if you want to use flutter_local_notifications, use the display() method.
  }

  static Future _onMessageOpenApp(RemoteMessage message) async {
    _messageStream.add(message);
    // implement your actions here
  }

  // iniciar firebase i notificacions locals
  static Future initializeApp() async {
    //Push notifications
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    idPush = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
    print('idPush: $idPush');
    //Handler
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_backgroundHandler);
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(_onMessageHandler);
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(_onMessageOpenApp);

    //local notifications initialization
    const InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
      iOS: DarwinInitializationSettings(),
      android: AndroidInitializationSettings("@mipmap/ic_notification"),
    );
    notificationPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
  }

  // mètode per obrir una notificació local (només amb l'app oberta)
  static void display(RemoteMessage message) async {
    try {
      await notificationPlugin.show(
        message.notification!.hashCode,
        message.notification!.title,
        message.notification!.body,
        NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            channel.id,
            channel.name,
            channelDescription: channel.description,
            color: Colors.blue,
            icon: '@mipmap/ic_notification',
          ),
          iOS: const DarwinNotificationDetails(
              presentAlert: true, presentBadge: true, presentSound: true),
        ),
      );
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  // demanar permisos
  Future<void> requestPermission() async {
    NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );

    if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
      print('User granted permission');
    } else if (settings.authorizationStatus ==
        AuthorizationStatus.provisional) {
      print('User granted provisional permission');
    } else {
      print('User declined or has not accepted permission');
    }
  }

  static closeStreams() {
    _messageStream.close();
  }
}
```

This class will show notifications when app is closed or in background. And if you need to display them with the app opened, you can throught the display method. If you want to save them to hive, just implement that part on the Handlers.
Finally initialize the class in your main:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await PushNotificationService.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Yes, I can show notification when app closed. There is no problem about this. But when app totally closed, I want to save device memory with hive package my received notification. Where can ı save above codes?